# How do you exclude some file extensions in Visual Studio Code Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a setting in Visual Studio Code that makes it possible to hide files with specific extensions such as *.js and *.js.map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your workspace settings (File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Workspace tab):

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": true,
        "**/*.js.map": true
    }
}
```

...depending on where your files are in the folder structure of course.

Comment: Thank you Ralph! I found that there was a Workspace Settings as well in which I could do the same configuration and achieve the same result.

Comment: NO worries. I think I meant workspace settings rather than user settings anyway - will update the answer for future viewers...